# .net encode and java decode

Tags: c#, java, .net, decode, encode

I have a string in c#. I want to send that string from .net web service to java after encoding.can any one suggest the procedure to encode a string in c# and decode the same in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us code from your webservice and java, so we can help you.

Comment: Just use utf8 encoding on both sides, and everything should work out of the box.

Comment: Hi Falanwe,Thanks for your reply.I have done utf8 encoding in .net and while decoding in java  I am using                                                                   **byte[] resultbytes= Base64.decodeBase64(result);
  
  String resultString=new String(resultbytes,"UTF-8");** but I am getting illegal argument exception saying,**' is not a valid XML character** . Please help me in solving this problem